# Как получить доступ к каталогу приложения на Android?

Tags: android-studio, файловая-система

У меня в приложении есть скрипт *(my_script)*, который я копирую в каталог с приложением и затем вызываю через терминал, например, `Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/user/0/my.package.app/files/my_script --version");`

Это работает на приставке с Android 7, но на Сбербокс с Андроид 9 и на смартфоне с Андроид 11 не работает.
Если вызвать эту команду на смартфоне с Андроид 11, то будет ошибка "inaccessible or not found", а на Сбербоксе просто "not found"

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем дело?
Может можно как-то проще запускать скрипт?

Answer (score 0):

Переименовать файл в `lib<name>.so`, затем поместить во все папки в **jniLibs**

Получить путь к файлу можно так: `getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/lib<name>.so"`

Пример: `/data/app/~~GoeS1231GPseyGfbY212fg==/you.package.app-21xvsvRGysqVb2_OXnI-DD==/lib/arm64/lib<name>.so`

Добавить в **manifest** `android:extractNativeLibs="true"`

Также добавить `implementation fileTree(include: ['.so'], dir: 'libs')` в **dependencies** в **build.gradle**

Этот ответ помог: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62394766/10946427